# Adding a space in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

```
// If given "George", "Washington" as arguments, it should return "Washington, George"
function formatName(firstName, lastName) {
  return [lastName, firstName];
}
```

Please see the link.  I can't figure out how to put a simple space between the first and last name.  I have been at this for hours please help!

Comment: Post your code as text not an image. What on earth were you attempting in this "hours" of effort?

Comment: You could do `return ${firstName} ${lastName}`

Answer (score 0):

Use String concatenation

```
return lastName +', '+ firstName;
```

```js
function formatName(firstName, lastName) {
  return lastName +', '+ firstName;
}

console.log(formatName("George","Washington"))
```

if your task is really to handle the given array than use the [`Array.prototype.join()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with the desired *separator* argument `', '`

```js
function formatName(firstName, lastName) {
  return [lastName, firstName].join(', ');
}

console.log(formatName("George","Washington"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return a string that concatenates the first name and last name. Try this:

```
return lastName +", "+ firstName;
```

Comment: This worked.  Thanks for the help I knew it was something simple!

Answer (score 0):

try with `join(', ')`

```
function formatName(firstName, lastName) {
  return [lastName, firstName].join(', ');
}
```